# multiple value select boxes not working

Tags: html, jquery-selectors

Tech Events
              Lan Games
              Fun Zone

when selected one by one it is displaying proper values via console.log()
but when selecting multiple values it is showing the same value as last repeated!

Comment: Post some code and maybe someone can help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//multiple  the id of multiselect
var foo = [];
$('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){
  foo[i] = $(selected).text();
});
```